# OpenStreetMaps offline tile packs

Tags: openstreetmap, data, united-states

Is there a place where I could download OpenStreetMaps tile packs for the united states? I would like to have offline access for the whole country.

Comment: So you are looking for RASTER tiles? 'tile packs'?

Comment: What application are you using? GIS/Phone/Tablet?

Comment: The US is just under 2% of the worlds area. Ignoring projection issues for a moment, http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_Disk_Usage and some multiplication will tell you how much stuff you're going to download and store, assuming you can find (or build) a source.

Comment: I am using a windows 7 32 bit tablet.

Comment: @BradHards Thanks for the link. I didn't see it from that perspective.

Comment: There are a lot of options for downloading. The most efficient method will depend on your workflow.  Here's a good resource: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data

Answer (score 5):

I think that the better approach for this would be to [download](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) the osm pbf data. Export it to tilemill and then convert them to the mbtiles format. Mapbox has a nice and easy to follow [tutorial](http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-ubuntu-quickstart/) for this. If you would like to have the look and feel of the Mapnik tiles you can check this [project](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto). You can then export these Mbtiles and use them for whatever purpose you want to use.

Comment: For testing, start with a smaller dataset by Geofabrik. It will save you hours of waiting to see the result...

Comment: This is your best bet.